# Hadoop API VS. Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

What is the difference when we run hadoop program with Streamer jar and when we run it with program's jar file?

Answer (score 5):

Usually we have Map/Reduce pair written in java..a map which splits the dataset into independent chunks, and a reduce which combines the results to perform some useful analysis...Hadoop streaming is a utility which allows us to write Map/Reduce applications in `any language(like Ruby/Python/Bash etc.)` that is capable of working with `STDIN(for input)` and `STDOUT(for output)`!

Comment: Yes , i have done it.But my question was what is difference.Like one i have found that with java mapreduce we can use inbuilt map and reduce class but when i did it in php with streamer , i didnt use it.

Comment: Well major benifit is the same as programs need not to know java to use Hadoop as Hadoop streaming is there...

Comment: but i am worried  if i will use other language other than java then i wont be able to use core hadoop functions.I looked for php thrift client , but link is dead and just now i found out php takes more time.In java when map starts correspondingly reduce starts , but in php reduce starts when map finishes.If you can provide me php thrift client , it will be helpful.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch02-mr-intro/src/main

Answer (score 0):

You're right to say that if you don't use Java you will not have the core hadoop functions available. THings like ChainMapper and ChainReducer, ChainedJobs and such are not available via streaming. Also, as Hadoop is written in Java, using Java will make it faster.

Also, another thing, theoretically, no reducer starts after the mapper is done. What you might see in the HTML as reducers running at the same time it's input being moved around.

Comment: Thnx again.But looks like now i have to leave this forum , i have got banned..Don't know for what reason..

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop Streaming enables us to write map and reduce functions in any programming or scripting language that supports reading data from standard input and writing to standard output. This feature makes Hadoop Streaming very flexible and can be easily used by a large number of users. R, Python, C++ , or pretty much any other language. 
There are a lot of parameters that can be customized, for example, number of mappers, number of reducers, jvm memory, input format, output format etc. The default input format for hadoop streaming jobs is TextInputFormat, which reads the data one line at a time.

Hadoop API
Pretty much binds you to Java, but the configuration and development is more straightforward since everything can be configured from the Java code itself. From my experience Java seems to be slightly faster, but streaming can get pretty close when properly configured and used with the right language.

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages** of Streaming:

1. Hadoop Streaming allows you to submit Map reduce jobs in your preferred scripting languages like Ruby, Python, Pig etc. The script may be translated into multiple Map Reduce jobs. You don't have to learn java.

**Disadvantages**.

1. The performance of Hadoop Streaming scripts is low compared to Hadoop API implementation using java. Reason is obvious - script is translated to multiple Map Reduce jobs and job completion time is very high since multiple jobs have to be completed.

Personally, I am more comfortable with Hadoop API with customer **Partitioner** & **Combiner** written in Java

Answer (score 0):

if you are programming with java then you compile and submit jobs regularly.  If you want to use other languages like Python or .NET then you can develop programs in these languages and streaming jar act like a bridge because these languages are not native hadoop which is java

Shahzad